# Error in opening InputStream from temp directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

**EDIT:** I recommend against saving .jasper files to the temp directory and then attempting to load from that location. It's a lot of trouble.

---

I am attempting to add JasperReport functionality to a Spring web app. The idea is that a pre-compiled .jasper file can be added to the server's Temp folder and filled then exported by the user.

I can successfully read .jrxml from the classpath, compile it into a `JasperReport`, fill it, and export it within the same method. In trying to separate these tasks, I've run into trouble. Specifically, when attempting to open an input stream from the temp directory.

The following code successfully creates a compiled .jasper file in the temp directory (I have omitted checks against filename for brevity).

```
Resource res = appContext.getResource("classpath:jasperreports/"
            + filename + ".jrxml");

File f = new File(
            org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaIoTmpDir(), filename
                    + ".jasper");       

JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStream(res.getInputStream(),
            new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Trying to READ from the temp folder causes a problem. After checking the temp folder for the newly-created .jasper, I call the following code.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String resourcePath = org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaIoTmpDir().getPath().toString();

Resource compiledReport = appContext.getResource(resourcePath + "/" + filename + ".jasper");
//Directly accessing the folder didn't work, either
//Resource compiledReport = appContext.getResource("C:/Users/<MyUsername Here>/AppData/Local/Temp/SimpleEmployeeReport.jasper");
JasperPrint filledReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport.getInputStream(), 
            params, mds.getConnection());
```

Which results in an exception thrown at getInputStream:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/<MyUsername>/AppData/Local/Temp/SimpleEmployeeReport.jasper]
```

I'd appreciate any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Can you open the temp directory in explorer to see if the file is there?

Comment: May be, you should try to create file with File.createTempFile()

Comment: Also, check path and permissions for it file. _f.canRead()_ _f.exists()_ _f.isFile()_ will help.

Comment: @dimoniy: Yes, I see the new .jasper file created/modified in temp.

Comment: @Ivan: I'll look those methods up.

Comment: If you look at the error message, it seems that it is trying to open the InputStream in the Servlet's context.  That would be in the classpath.  So, it's looking for `/C:/Users...`, not `C:/Users...`. I'd bet that leading `/` is the problem.

Comment: @CodeChimp: I just retried the whole process, but with a string (with \\ escape characters to account for the Windows convention, just to be sure) `"C:\\Users\\<MyUsername>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\filename.jasper"` and got the same error.

Comment: @WidthInEms I am not saying there is a problem with the direction of the slashes, it's that you have a leading slash (/) prior to the `C:` part. There should not be a leading '/'. I think you need to print out all of the parts, starting with `org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaIoTmpDir()` and `filename + ".jasper"`, print the absolute and relative paths of `File f`, and as Ivan suggested, print out the results of `f.canRead()`, `f.exists()`, `f.isFile()` etc.

Comment: @CodeChimp Console dump results from upper code block with argument string filename being "SimpleEmployeeReport": `f.canRead(): true ---f.exists(): true --- f.isFile(): true --- getJavaIoTmpDir: C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\Temp --- filename + .jasper: SimpleEmployeeReport.jasper --- f.getAbsolutePath(): C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\Temp\SimpleEmployeeReport.jasper --- f.getCanonicalPath(): C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\Temp\SimpleEmployeeReport.jasper`
I stepped through the lower code block, and resourcePath evaluates to `C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: @WidthInEms So, you are using a straight-up `File` to write it out, but you are using the `ApplicationContext`s `getResource()` to read it back in?  Can you try prepending the string with `"file://"` and see if that is handled better?  Keep the forward `/`s in the actual path part of the string.

Comment: @dimoniy Thank you for your help! I will not be loading from the temp directory anymore, as I have been directed otherwise by the higher-ups. I hope to vote your comments up when I have enough reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ivan I attempted to add you to my previous comment, but SO wouldn't let me. Thank you to you!

Comment: @CodeChimp Again, tried to add you to the first thank-you post, so thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Multipart held tmp files that caused new file names. Creating my own temp directory solved the issue. On `Linux` the `getProperty` is missing the trailing slash

```
    String tempDirectory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    if(  !tempDirectory .endsWith("/") && !tempDirectory .endsWith( "\\") ) {
        tempDirectory = tempDirectory +"/";
```